# Spring AMQP RPC Non-default exchange

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp, spring-amqp

Is there a way to using the `sendAndRecieve()` method from the `RabbitTemplate` and use the non-default exchange. I know I can use the `setReplyQueue()` method but that is limited to the default exchange.

Right now the only way I get around this is by manually passing the `reply-to` when building the message, and send synchronously and receive afterwards.

Thanks in advance, hopefully its just an oversight of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open an [Improvement JIRA Issue](http://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

The listener supports a `replyTo` with the form `exchange/routingKey` - see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#async-annotation-driven-reply).

However, the rabbit Template doesn't support setting it up that way for send and receive operations, it sets up reply routing using the default exchange and queue name as the rk.

Unfortunately, I don't see an easy work around.

EDIT: removed my suggested workaround - it won't work because the method references private fields.

EDIT2: I found another work-around by configuring the template with Java instead of XML...

https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/commit/47d8238fd8651ed3a04eab7c91fae632c7f3155c

Comment: Thanks! I saw the commit, I used a a replyTo with a listener that was bound to a fixed queue with same routingKey as its named...not very elegant. I think RPC calls should all be made over the default exchange!! Thanks for your help!